# What does it mean to be a polynomial in the entries of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm a bit confused by this statement.

> The coefficients of $p_A(x)$ are polynomials in the entries of $A$

I'm practically new to linear algebra and a simple explanation or some examples might help. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose $p_A(x)$ denotes the characteristic polynomial of a square matrix $A$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$p_A(x)$ is presumably some polynomial function of $x$, with the form

$p_A(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \dots + a_nx^n$

where the $\{a_i\}$ are its coefficients. If the coefficients are "polynomial in the entries of $A$" then this just means that each $a_i$ is the sum of products of powers of the elements of $A$.

For example, if

$A=\left( \begin{matrix} a&b \\c&d \end{matrix} \right)$

then

$\det (A^2-xI) = \left|\left( \begin{matrix} a^2+bc-x&b(a+d) \\c(a+d)&d^2+bc-x \end{matrix} \right)\right| \\= x^2 -(a^2+2bc+d^2)x +(a^2d^2 + b^2c^2 -2abcd)$

has coefficients that are polynomials in $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Thanks for this! This helped a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

This simply means that the coefficients of $x^k$ in the expression $p_A(x),$ where $k$ is a nonnegative integer, are polynomial functions of $a_{ij},$ with $1\le i\le m, 1\le j\le n,$ where $A$ is of order $m\times n.$

And by a polynomial function of the terms $a_{ij}$ is meant a combination of these terms using only a finite number of additions and multiplications.